# Trying to import a Neo4j database into Gephi

Tags: neo4j, gephi

When i try to import my `Neo4j` database into `Gephi` nothing happens and i get the empty warning message window.

Environment is `Gephi 0.8.2` on `Mac OSX 10.9.2` with `Neo4j 2.1.2`

I have installed the `Neo4j plugin v. 2.1.0` which appears to be the latest.`Neo4j` graph data is in the default graph.db directory

> File ->Neo4j Database -> Full Import ->graph.db

Any help most appreciated

Comment: Are you running Gephi under Java 7 ? Neo4j needs Java7.

Comment: Gephi needs Java 6, so did the fix to have Gephi point to 6 while Neo4j runs on 7 but now i can't add the Neo4j plugin 'cause Gephi complains that it need Java 7 for the plugin ... have seen many comments regarding this, but haven't been able to find a definitive solutions yet :(

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j plugin currently supports only neo4j 2.1.0. I submitted a (still pending) [pull request](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/pull/48) for an upgrade to 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is now updated to use Neo4j 2.1.3 https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/commit/145dcc5fc2d9008838dd434239674e3e20b0521c

Comment: I take it that the gephi plugin won't work with my Neo4j 3.0.3 then hmm?